# ajax not return anything when checkbox is checked

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a list of manufacturers with checkbox when i checkbox is checked ajax is called and hit the controller but not return anything

I am using laravel 5.1

```
    @foreach($manufacturers as $leedsManufacturer) {{-- @foreach($leedManufacturers as $leedsManufacturer) --}}
                                <div class="post" id="post{{$leedsManufacturer['mfgg_id']}}">
                                    <label class=" my-checkbox gry2" id="manufacturer">{{str_limit($leedsManufacturer['mfgg_name'], 300)}}
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="manufacturer common_selector" name="manufacturer[]" value="{{$leedsManufacturer['mfgg_id']}}">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    </label>

                                </div>
                                    @endforeach 
                                @endif
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        filter_data();

        function filter_data() {

            var manufacturer = get_filter('manufacturer');
            // var products = get_filter('products');
            // var chps_approved = get_filter('chps_approved');

            $.ajax({

                url: "{{url('ajax1')}}",
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                data:{manufacturer:manufacturer} ,

                success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                }

            });

            // alert(manufacturers);
        }

        function get_filter(class_name) {

            var filter = [];

            $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });

        alert(filter);
        // return filter
        }

        $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    });
```

controller

```
public function ajax1(Request $request){

    $data= $request->manufacturer;
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

On checkbox select, it should return the ID so i can use it in controller. but `$request->manufacturer` show this on console.

Comment: can I see your route for the controller? what method you are using, change it to 'any'

Comment: Please console the error function in ajax .  error: function (data){
                console.log(data);
                }

Comment: are you sure you are getting the id from the view?

Comment: is this  url: "{{url('ajax1')}}" in your blade file or your js file, if it is in your js file, then i will not work, cause it will not be rendered, you need hidden input to have those value in the checkbox and then pull it down to you js file

Answer (score 0):

try this lets see if you are getting the id from the form.  i use javascript alert

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        filter_data();

        function filter_data() {

            var manufacturer = get_filter('manufacturer');

            alert(manufacturer);

            // var products = get_filter('products');
            // var chps_approved = get_filter('chps_approved');

            $.ajax({

                url: "{{url('ajax1')}}",
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                data:{manufacturer:manufacturer} ,

                success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                }

            });

            // alert(manufacturers);
        }

        function get_filter(class_name) {

            var filter = [];

            $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });

        alert(filter);
        // return filter
        }

        $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    });
```